# Texlive, update and dvips

Tags: texlive, updating, dvips

When I run `tlmgr update -all`, I see that, or at least I understand that the engine `dvips` is updated at some point. If yes, what is updated in `dvips`?

[image]

Comment: This topic is very specific, you could make it more generic by asking »How to find out what changed between updates of packages and/or engines?«. Or something similar.

Comment: Agreed.  It's a good question in concept, but as it stands it's too specific.

Comment: Whenever a font package is installed or updated, the map files are updated as well; they are under `dvips`. See http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=33216 for the list of updated files in this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *package* `dvips` contains all font and PostScript specific stuff and not the program itself (which is in a package like `dvips.<binary type>`):

```
 texmf-dist/doc/dvips/dvips.html
 texmf-dist/doc/dvips/dvips.pdf
 texmf-dist/doc/info/dvips.info
 texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/afm2tfm.1
 texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/afm2tfm.man1.pdf
 texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/dvips.1
 texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/dvips.man1.pdf
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/crop.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/ehandler.ps
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/finclude.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/hps.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/resolution400.ps
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/texc.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/alt-rule.pro
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/canonex.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.bakoma
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.canonex
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.cx
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.deskjet
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.dvired
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.epson
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ibmvga
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ljfour
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.luc
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.mbn
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.mga
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.mirrorprint
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ot2
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ps
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.qms
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.toshiba
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.unms
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.xyp
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/cx.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/deskjet.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/dfaxhigh.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/dvired.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/epson.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/ibmvga.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/ljfour.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/qms.cfg
 texmf-dist/dvips/config/toshiba.cfg
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/6w.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/7t.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8a.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/ad.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/ansinew.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/asex.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/asexp.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/dc.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/dvips.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/ec.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/extex.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/funky.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/odvips.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-cs-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-ec-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-l7x-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-qx-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-rm-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-t2a-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-t2b-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-t2c-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-t5-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-texnansi-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/q-ts1-uni.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/qx.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/stormex.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/tex256.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/texmext.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/texmital.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/texmsym.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/texnansx.enc
 texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/builtin35.map
 texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/download35.map
 texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map
 texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
 texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_pk.map
 texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts_t1.map
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips/blackdvi.sty
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips/blackdvi.tex
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips/colordvi.sty
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips/colordvi.tex
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips/rotate.sty
 texmf-dist/tex/generic/dvips/rotate.tex
```

If anything changes in this area then the TeXLive package `dvips` is updated.